# iPhone - can Cocos2d create non-games?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Can Cocos2D create non-game apps like, for example, a finger painting application, a questionnaire or other kind of app that is not a game?

If so, what kind of limitations did the library has for this kind of app?

If not, what kind of library do you suggest?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create any app with custom look and feel with cocos2d. It is a library that gives you high level support over raw opengl like creating and managing scenes, lots of animation etc. etc. What you can do is limited by your imagination :-). And as suggested by Jesse Naugher, check out the features. And also check their sample for iPhone.

just trying to give an example. in general u will need some button, menu etc. and u will need to transit from one scene to another. say in the home screen u will show a menu containing 4 options and upon selecting u will move to 4 different screens. say in the first screen u take some input and process data and show some result to the user. say another one screen shows a pie chart and another one shows bar chart. and another screen contains options / settings for user. u can do all of these with cocos2d.

Comment: do you know some example of an app, not a game, done with cocos2d?

Comment: sorry, i cant provide u an example. the main reason is most of the companies dont say what technology / tool they have used. so its difficult to guess what actually is used in an app. but if u look into cocos2d features and run sample codes, then u will realize that its possible to build almost any custom ui with it. obviously u wont get the default look and feel like a navigation bar or tab bar, but surely u dont want them in a opengl app. the summary is, cocos2d makes it easier to handle opengl in 2d environment and u can do any funny custom ui with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is for any graphical application as far as its limitations, I'd suggest reading up on their website, it is fairly in depth and useful. [cocos2d](http://cocos2d-iphone.org/)

Comment: thanks,  but I don't see any non-game app there. I would like to see an example or tutorial or something graphical done with cocos2d.

Comment: i have added an example with my answer (its big to fit in comment). hope it helps u.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. cocos2d isn't only used to create games, but that is the most common purpose for it. It will let you control scenes and animation much easier.

An example of an app that uses cocos2d but isn't a game is [mystic](http://cardilloscreations.com/apps/iphone/mystic.html). It should give you a basic idea of some of the things that cocos2d is designed to do (animation and control scenes).